# how to create label in the table header in iphone applications?

Tags: objective-c

Hi all i have create a table at run time while loading the page. How to create a label at run time and assign a text to the label in the table header section.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make your data source return the correct `NSString` in `-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;`.

If you have others requirements than just displaying text in the header, implement this table view delegate method :

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```